# can't group Push Buttons

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

i'm trying to group multi (Push Buttons) into an exclusive group, but i don't know how,
when i tried this example [[Link]](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?index=604&key=QPushButtonExclusive) on its own  it worked,
but when i try it on my project it failed

NOTE: all my UI elements are graphically implemented not code implemented,
also i'm using (Qt Creator) only

i tried the following

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Test01 window;

       QButtonGroup apple (&window);
        apple.addButton(&PB01);
        apple.addButton(&PB02);
        apple.addButton(&PB03);
        apple.setExclusive(true);

    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

but it didn't work, not the following either

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Test01 window;

    QButtonGroup apple (&window);
        apple.addButton(&ui->PB01);
        apple.addButton(&ui->PB02);
        apple.addButton(&ui->PB03);
        apple.setExclusive(true);

    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

i tried on the cpp file, like the following

```
Test01::Test01(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Test01)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QButtonGroup apple (&Test01);
        apple.addButton(&ui->PB01);
        apple.addButton(&ui->PB02);
        apple.addButton(&ui->PB03);
        apple.setExclusive(true);
}
```

but didn't work either

- can you please provide the solution
- also what's the deference between write this code in (main.cpp) & in (test01.cpp) file

Comment: What does *"didn't work"* mean? Did you get compiler errors, runtime errors, wrong results, ...? If you got errors please add the error messages to your question (including which line causes them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer your question correctly, it would be nice to provide the `ui`-Code of your form.

Howevery, one reason could be, that you missed the `checkable` property of `QPushButton`.

To work as a button group every `QPushButton` must be marked as `checkable` either by code:

```
PB01->setCheckable(true);
```

or by Qt Designer.

Greetings, Thomas

Comment: you are right 
i didn't make the buttons checkable, but i made it so in graphically manner again,
via (Property Editor) not by code 
any way i will seek this out after a while
thank you for your help my friend